# Restrict Google picker by country Nepal

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I used bounds but it shows everywhere. How to restrict the google autopicker by Nepal.My country code is NP. I expect the correct answer.

Comment: share some code.

Comment: you can use AutocompleteFilter to filter the country

Comment: Here is an example AutocompleteFilter filter = 
    new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setCountry("NP").build();

Comment: did you solved it ?

Comment: thanks a lot. i need help in future too.